# Should a Modbus TCP client expect messages with no MBAP header?

Tags: modbus, modbus-tcp

I am writing a Modbus TCP client program from scratch and use the Pymodslave simulator for testing. Pymodslave uses unit id `01`. If I send a message with a different unit id, for example `FF`, Pymodslave responds with an exception message that consists of the PDU only and has no MBAP header.

Raw request data (Read Holding Registers, address 160, 1 register):

```
00 00 00 00 00 06 FF 03 00 A0 00 01
```

Raw response data:

```
83 04
```

This is the PDU of a Server Device Failure exception response.

**My question is: Should my client program handle such a PDU-only message with no MBAP header, or does this look like a quirk of Pymodslave?**

Here is a little more context.

If the unit id is what Pymodslave expects then it always sends a full ADU. Here are two examples:

If I change the unit id byte in the request from `FF` to `01` then the messages are:

Request:

```
00 00 00 00 00 06 FF 03 00 A0 00 01
```

Response (success, register value is zero):

```
00 00 00 00 00 05 01 03 02 00 00
```

If I use the correct unit id and an invalid register number `FFFF` then the exception response has an MBAP header:
Request:

```
00 00 00 00 00 06 01 03 FF FF 00 01
```

Response (exception, Illegal Data Address):

```
00 00 00 00 00 03 01 83 02
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familiar with the slave you're using but in my experience, most slaves ignore messages that are not addressed to them.

Quoting from the [Modbus spec](http://www.modbus.org/docs/PI_MBUS_300.pdf):

> Slaves return a message (called a ‘response’) to queries that are
>   addressed to them individually

So if the query is not directed to them they should simply ignore it. Which in your case means you should be getting a timeout error on the master.

Although I cannot guarantee they are fully compliant with the spec, I find [Win-Tech](https://www.win-tech.com/html/modbus1.htm) tools very reliable if you have a Windows machine. I've also used *pymodbus* and *libmodbus* quite extensively and other than minor bugs I've never had any complaints. I'm not encouraging you to drop *pymodslave* but you might want to take a look at the code to see why you're getting that response.

Nothing that should worry you too much but according to the Modbus specification slave valid addresses range from 1 to 247 so you should not be using `0xFF` as a slave ID if you want to comply. Most hardware vendors stick to this rule and won't allow addresses over 247.